# Trouble stopping camera after page change in Next.js project

Tags: html, reactjs

In my webpage, I use the getUserMedia function to obtain a video stream and set up a cleanup function to stop the stream when the page is unmounted. However, when I navigate to another page, even though the log prints "stop stream" and "stop video," the browser still shows that the camera is active. I'm wondering why this happens and how to resolve it?

```
  useEffect(() => {
    let animate: number | null = null;
    let stream: MediaStream | null = null;
    const video = videoRef.current;
    const handleDraw = async () => {
      if (!video) {
        return;
      }
      stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        video: {
          width: { ideal: 4096 },
          height: { ideal: 2160 },
          facingMode: 'environment',
        },
      });
      video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', () => {
        video.play();
      });
      video.srcObject = stream;
      const draw = () => {
        // some draw logic
        animate = requestAnimationFrame(draw);
      };
      animate = requestAnimationFrame(draw);
    };
    handleDraw();
    return () => {
      if (animate) {
        cancelAnimationFrame(animate);
        if (stream) {
          console.log('stop stream');
          stream.getTracks().forEach((track) => {
            track.stop();
          });
        }
        if (video) {
          console.log('stop video');
          video.load();
          stream = null;
        }
      }
    };
  }, []);
```

I've attempted using video.pause() and also tried using document.selectById, but unfortunately, neither of these methods seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

Encountered the same issue recently.

Observed that the camera only turns off on the page reload in this case.

Haven't been able to figure out an exact solution to this yet.

As a workaround, using router.push to a specific URL on window.popstate event does the job for me in this case, would still need a better solution for this.

Sample code:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    startCamera();

    const handlePopstate = () => {
        router.replace("/xyz");
    };

    window.addEventListener("popstate", handlePopstate);

    return () => {
        stopCamera();
    };
}, []);
```